# Access to the path is denied, after already being accessed?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

In my current program, I have the main method which contains

```
using (NetworkShareAccessor.Access(---credentials etc---)
{
       (string latest = new DirectoryInfo(---folder on the network---).GetDirectories().OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTimeUTC).First().ToString();

       CopyFiles(latest, "---folder---", "---file name---");
}
```

This successfully accesses the network folder, and I know because if I choose to Console.WriteLine(latest), it outputs the correct folder to the console, proving that the fodler has been accessed. However, in my CopyFiles method, I get the unhandled exception which states:

> Access to the path '---path location---' is denied

I need to use the external method and can't simply put it all in Main() because it will be used elsewhere and repeated, so it makes more sense to have it's own method and pass in different parameters which contain a folder name and a file name.

I have already tried putting everything within the CopyFiles method within it's own using statement which I have used in the Main Method, but this doesn't work either. FYI here is the code used in the CopyFiles Method

```
static void CopyFiles(string mostRecentFolder, string installerFolder, string installerName)
    {
        string sourcePath = string.Format(@"\\---network directory---\{0}\{1}", mostRecentFolder,
            installerFolder, installerName);
        string targetPath = string.Format(@"C:\Temp\");

        if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);

        string sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourcePath, installerName);
        string destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, installerName);

        File.Copy(sourcePath, destFile, true);
    }
```

Comment: in this line `File.Copy(sourcePath, destFile, true);` put a breakpoint and tell us what the value of `sourcePath and destFile` is.. also a better way to know if you have access to the network directory is either manually check your permissions or navigate to that network share and see if you can manually create an empty text file.. don't assume anything when coding..

Comment: @MethodMan both values are what I would expect them to be, and manually, I _am_ able to create a txt file and manipulate the files and folders etc.

Comment: can you show us the value(s) also this is incorrect.. 
`string sourcePath = string.Format(@"\\---network directory---\{0}\{1}", mostRecentFolder,
            installerFolder, installerName);` where is the `"{2}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:
File.Copy(sourcePath, destFile, true);

Try:
 File.Copy(**sourceFile**, destFile, true);

Comment: Ah - yes, please add some elaboration - because they've got two very similarly named variables, they seem to have used `sourcePath` when `sourceFile` is the more obvious value to use.

Comment: Thanks @Steji , I was expecting it to be something small and trivial like that!

Answer (score 0):

Try including your file name in the path, this seems to be the reason for your error.